# When is the time recorded when you Answer a question?

Tags: support, reputation, timestamps, high-rep-users

I had a [seemingly] strange thing happen today.  I answered a question and when I saved it, I was the only answer shown.

Later, I came back to add some additional information, and there was a high-rep user with an answer listed with a timestamp *before* mine.

This made me think, does the timestamp on answers reflect when you *start* to answer a question, or when you actually *post* the question?

I had thought the latter until today, but it seems to me either...

1. The former is true and timestamps are based upon when you start your answer.
2. The site didn't update my browser properly when I saved my response.
3. A high-rep gives one the ability to modify timestamps and someone is using this to increase rep.

What *does* the timestamp reflect?  *Posted* time or *Start* time?

Comment: Or perhaps the other answer was posted while you were writing yours and you didn't reload the page?

Comment: ^almost certainly that. A user can also delete their answer then undelete it, but this would show in revision history.

Comment: Also, could you post a link to the question? I can't see any of your answers on SO for today where a high-rep user would have posted an answer before you, so perhaps it was on some other site?

Comment: It was on SO, and it was recent.  I would rather not post a link to the specific question publicly only because I don't want to cast unfair dispersions on another user.  I'll be happy to send it privately to those who care.  However, I'm now fairly certain the above comments are correct and I just didn't get the update.

Comment: @Donovan If you check the revision history and it was deleted/undeleted, then OGHaza is right.  If not, then you just didn't see it.

Comment: I don't see how posting the link would be unfair because this has nothing to do with the other user's post or actions. Anyway going through your posts on SO for the past 2 days none of those match the description. Are you *really* sure the other answer's timestamp is before yours?

Comment: It was this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747024/how-this-awk-is-replacing-an-if

Comment: However, now it seems correct... bizarre.  Perhaps I just need to put the crack pipe down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#2 Is the case here.

The answer really was posted before yours, you just didn't see it.  The option to load other answers asynchronously without a full page load does take *some* time to load answers, so if it was posted very shortly before yours, you might not have seen it.  It's also possible for there to have been an error in loading it asynchronously; it happens from time to time (especially with an unreliable internet).

Timestamps are based on when the answer is posted, not started, and users (or even moderators) cannot edit a post's timestamp.

Comment: Do you know if posting an answer yields a page reload? (I could *try* myself, of course...)

Comment: @Arjan It does not.  It would normally asynchronously add answers posted since you posted yours, but if there was an error with the web socket, if it was disabled, had issues with a firewall, etc. then that might not have happened.

Comment: But then upon posting the answer, all answers currently known would have been shown when the page was reloaded?

Comment: @Arjan See my previous comment.

Comment: Ah, "No" as in "No, posting your answer does not reload the page". Then all is explained :-)

Comment: ...but still curious I tried anyway. And it seems that posting a new answer [does do a full reload](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OzPzT.png)...? Then I'd assume that all known answers would have shown. Or maybe some cached page was loaded from the server then.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp reflects the time your answer was received by the system, not the time you started writing it. And no, high rep users can't mess with timestamps. Only our beloved developers can so that.